# How to add Categery name url in category page

Tags: category, url-rewrite, magento2.4

At present my category page URl is https://myshop.com/catalog/category/view/s/handbag/id/54/. I need to change Category page URL like https://myshop.com/handbag.

Please let me know which file want to change?

Answer (score 4):

Create Category Rewrites

Step 1: Add the Rewrite

- On the Admin Panel, Marketing > [SEO &
  Search] > URL Rewrites.
- In the upper-right corner, click on Add URL Rewrites. From the
  dropdown list of Create URL Rewrites, choose “For Category” option.
- In the category tree, find the category you want to redirect.
- In the URL Rewrite section, you can:

  ```
  Set the Store to apply the rewrites if necessary.
  In the Request Path field, insert the new URL key and suffix for the product.
  ```
- Convert Redirect to Temporary (302) or Permanent (301).
  Leave some description for the rewrite.
- Save to complete.

Step 2: Update the Index

- On the Admin Panel, System > Tools > Index Management.
- Mark the Catalog URL Rewrites checkbox.
- Choose Reindex Data.
- Submit to update the index,Test changes.

Comment: Please consider marking this answer as solution to your question of it provided the information you were looking for, so others can benefit from it too.